# how to receive array data in ajax request page wordpress

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I am sending array to PHP through angularJs $http, but when I receiving data it was showing null, I don't know is that my procedure is correct or not,

js file is

```
var newdisable_comments_on_post_types = JSON.stringify(allTabData.disable_comments_on_post_types);
$http({
        method:'post',
        url:url,
        params:{
       'disable_comments_on_post_types': newdisable_comments_on_post_types
                }
        });
```

while sending in the header it sending like this

```
disable_comments_on_post_types:{"post":false,"page":false,"attachment":false}
```

in the PHP file, i did some of the procedure to receive it

```
$a = $_POST['disable_comments_on_post_types']['post'];// method 1

$a = $_POST['disable_comments_on_post_types'] // method 2
$x=1
foreach($a as $val){
$b[$x]=$val;
$x++;
}

$a = $_POST['disable_comments_on_post_types']->post;// method 3
```

I am getting null in response every method while I returning data to check

```
echo json_encode($a);
```

am I doing any wrong or in WordPress we cant send an array to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your **$http service** to this:

> By default, the $http service will transform the outgoing request by
>   serializing the data as JSON and then posting it with the content-
>   type, "application/json"

```
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
            var str = [];
            for(var p in obj)
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            return str.join("&");
        },
        data: allTabData.disable_comments_on_post_types
    }).success(function () {});
```